# SPARQL: Get "most specific property"

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

I'm trying to fetch the most specific properties for a class, and I'm stuck. I want to pull out all the properties that apply for a given class (including those inherited from superclasses), **except** those properties that have subproperties in the result set.

For example, if I have a class *Population* with one of its properties being *atLocation*, and a subclass of *Population* called *Refugees*. *Refugees* has a property *currentLocation*, which is a subProperty of *atLocation*.

So what I want is a generic query that would give me **only** *atLocation* if I put in *Population*, and **only** *currentLocation* if I put in *Refugees*.  What I have is this:

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
prefix ex: <http://example.org/vocabulary#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?prop WHERE {
  ex:Refugee rdfs:subClassOf* ?domain  .
  ?prop rdfs:domain ?domain .
  ?subprop rdfs:domain ?domain .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?subprop rdfs:subPropertyOf ?prop . }  
} ORDER BY ?prop
```

This gives me both *atLocation* **and** *currentLocation*, though.

Is this possible in one query at all? Any ideas on how to solve this appreciated!

Comment: Same question also posted (and answered) on W3C sparql-dev mailinglist, see http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-sparql-dev/2012JulSep/0017.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was trickier than I anticipated when I tried it for myself.
However, what you need to do is extend your NOT EXISTS clause somewhat.

```
SELECT ?prop WHERE {
  ?prop rdfs:domain ?domain .
  ?class rdfs:subClassOf* ?domain .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {
        ?sub rdfs:subPropertyOf ?prop.
        ?sub rdfs:domain ?d.
        ?class rdfs:subClassOf* ?d .
  }
  FILTER (?class = ex:Refugee)
}
```

We're selecting all properties whose domain is ex:Refugee or a
superclass of ex:Refugee (first two BGPs). But then we want to filter
out those properties for which a subProperty exists that also has a
domain which is (a superclass of) ex:Refugee. Note that we are using a
different variable for the domain of the sub-property (?d), after all it
does not necessarily have to have the exact same domain as the property
we are selecting.

The above works on a simple (non-entailment or RDF(S) entailment)
triplestore, provided each sub-property only has its most specific
domain class defined, that is, you have the triple 'ex:currentLocation
rdfs:domain ex:Refugee' but not explicitly 'ex:currentLocation
rdfs:domain ex:Population'.

Comment: Thanks, Jeen. I was just about to paste your answer here, in case someone else has the same problem in the future.

Comment: @Carsten, you didn't think I was gonna let you get away with those karma points right? :)